# C dynamic allocation of struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-allocation, code-composer

I have a problem trying to dynamically allocate a struct in C:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t wifiSSID[30];
    uint8_t wifiPassword[20];
}
tWifiPair;


typedef struct
{
    tWifiPair *wifiNetworks; // this needs to become an array with 2 elements
    // if I do the above like this tWifiPair wifiNetworks[1] - all works fine
}
tEEPROMSettings;

tEEPROMSettings gEEPROMSettings;

int main()
{
    gEEPROMSettings.wifiNetworks = (tWifiPair *)calloc(2, sizeof(tWifiPair));

    // .... writing to gEEPROMSettings.wifiNetworks[0].wifiSSID crashes the program, unfortunately I can't see the error, but the compiler doesn't throw any errors/warnings
}
```

If this tWifiPair *wifiNetworks is done staticly - tWifiPair wifiNetworks[1] - it works fine, but I need to do it dynamically and possibly change it while the program is running.

This is running on an embedded platform - ARM tm4c1294ncpdt, compiler is CCS6.

Can you point me to where the error is? Thanks!

Comment: What is the code that is writing to `gEEPROMSettings.wifiNetworks[0].wifiSSID`? The crash could be from that code.

Comment: Also, what sort of environment is this? It could be a linker configuration issue which could explain why heap usage fails, but static usage works.

Comment: Did you `#include <stdlib.h>`? Casting the return of `malloc()` and friends can hide a bug that in the worst case can cause a crash when using the memory.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but you don't need to cast the return value of `calloc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the return value of `calloc` to make sure it succeeded.

> On success, a pointer to the memory block allocated by the function.
>   The type of this pointer is always void*, which can be cast to the desired type of data pointer in order to be dereferenceable.
>   If the function failed to allocate the requested block of memory, a null pointer is returned.

From [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/)

Now, if `calloc` is failing, that is another question.

Updating with info from comments for others reading:

This appears to be an embedded system, which may have a small heap configured. `calloc` does return `NULL`, so the allocation is failing. Depending on your compiler/linker, you may need to adjust a linker script, scatter file, or project options to change the heap size.

Comment: I _seriously_ doubt this is a memory allocation failure.

Comment: I was about to say it's unlikely this is the issue, but... I can't think of any other possibility...

Comment: @SeanBright, if this is running in an embedded system, there may be no/limited heap space, and it could genuinely not have any memory to allocate. Given that there's an EEPROM type, that leads me to believe that it could be embedded.

Comment: Also, you should *always* check your allocation calls for failed returns.

Comment: @rjp yes it's embedded, but there should be plenty of free ram I guess, and just tripled the stack. Yet it works if I staticly create it as an array[2], if that makes any difference...

Comment: @LachoTomov, it's not the stack size that needs to increase, but the heap. Can you add some details to the question about the environment you're running? OS, architecture, compiler, etc.

Comment: @rjp Oh actually you're right... if (gEEPROMSettings.wifiNetworks == NULL) -> this returns true.
I'm running it on an ARM - tm4c1294ncpdt, code composer studio. I'll check how to increase the heap here... Many thanks!

Comment: It's usually in your linker script file (sometimes called scatter file), but I haven't used CCS. It may be a project option somewhere as well.

Comment: Found it, it was a project option, and was set to 0. I changed it to 512 and now everything works fine. Many thanks!

Comment: @SeanBright it seems one should not take your doubts too seriously ;)

Comment: @LachoTomov that may not be such a good fix; if you try to increase the size of the allocation due to runtime conditions then you still may run into trouble with the larger heap limit.  To be reliable you should allocate the maximum amount you ever need, right at the start (be it static or heap - static is simpler but it depends on the system setup of course). When you increase heap size you may simply be reducing static data size by the same amount so you didn't really gain much.

Comment: @MattMcNabb oh I see your point now. At first I thought with dynamic allocation I'll escape from the hardcoded array limits, but it's obviously still limited by the heap size... I'll think about it, thanks.